# How to use jquery to parse a view and attach listeners to '<a>' tags?

Tags: jquery

I wrote some simply code to load views. When I load a view, I need to parse the view for `<a>` tags that need to have listeners attached. Initially, I parse the whole document, but this lead to some strange error where the whole document would be parsed n times where n is the number of times I clicked a hyperlink. Very weird stuff. Now I am trying to parse only the inner view. How can I tell jquery to start off from a jquery element that I provide (the view that I load).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewRoot = $("[view='']");

        function attachHyperLinkListener() {
            $('a').filter(function (index, element) {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                console.log('analyzing ' + href);
                if ( href.substring(0, 2) == "#/" ) {
                    console.log('attaching listener');
                    return (href.substring(0, 2) == "#/");
                }
                return false;
            }).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(2)
                loadPage(href);
                var stateObj = {'href' : href};
                window.history.pushState(stateObj, '', href);
            });
        }

        function loadPage(href) {
            console.log('loading ' + href );
            $.get(href, null, function (data) {
                var view = $.parseHTML(data)
                viewRoot.html(view);
                //attachHyperLinkListener(); // running this causes that strange error
               // how can I run $('a').click(...) on 'view' only?
            });
        }

        $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
            loadPage(e.originalEvent.state.href);
        });

        window.history.pushState({'href':'/'}, '', ''); // push the original page
        attachHyperLinkListener();
    });
</script>
```

[edit] I think the error occurs because there are n listeners on the same `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewRoot.on('click', 'a', function () {
    // here you go
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I had no idea you could do this. I solved the problem by using unbind after the filter but since this answers my original question, I will accept it. Thanks!